# Spring Boot 3.2 automatically change log level during shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2

We recently upgraded springBoot version to 3.2, and Java 21 64 bit.
We observed wired behaviour while shutting down spring boot application , log level automatically change INFO to ERROR, and we are not getting expected log messages.

After so many research, we found there is a feature "automatic log level propagation".

We have some important INFO messages that should appear during application off.

We tried to disable with few properties like :
management.tracing.enabled = false
spring.main.log-shutdown-info = true

But nothing help, it is still ERROR.

Please suggest and help what we can do to get INFO level at end of application.

We need INFO log level while spring boot application is shutting down.

As per Shutdown Log when run the application with argument `-Dlog4j2.debug` : `TRACE StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] AsyncLoggerDisruptor: disruptor has been shut down` :

**Shutdown log**

```
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class jp.co.tec.ngp.broker.device.controller.DeviceAdminApiContoller
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class jp.co.tec.ngp.broker.device.admin.DeviceAdminServiceImpl
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class jp.co.tec.ngp.broker.device.admin.BrokerAdminServiceImpl
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class jp.co.tec.ngp.broker.service.impl.BrokerServiceImpl
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.transport.FutureResponse
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.management.JMSEndpointStatsImpl
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory
DEBUG StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] AsyncLoggerDisruptor: shutting down disruptor for this context.
TRACE StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] AsyncLoggerDisruptor: disruptor has been shut down.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=AsyncContext@25bbe1b6, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@45d2ade3]...
WARN StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] Ignoring log event after log4j was shut down: INFO [jp.co.tec.ngp.broker.device.base.statemachine.BaseStateMachineListener] [stateChanged] -------------------------------------------
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@25bbe1b6]
WARN StatusLogger Ignoring log event after log4j was shut down
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@25bbe1b6,component=StatusLogger]
WARN StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] Ignoring log event after log4j was shut down: INFO [jp.co.tec.ngp.broker.device.base.statemachine.BaseStateMachineListener] [stateChanged] Device- CashChanger state change to sub state STOPPED
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@25bbe1b6,component=ContextSelector]
WARN StatusLogger Ignoring log event after log4j was shut down
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more information. What version are you upgrading from? Did that version work as expected or are you doing something new? What is the "automatic log level propagation" feature you're referring to? If possible could you provide a sample application that shows the problem?

Comment: We upgraded Spring boot 2.7 to 3.2. and Java 11 to 21 64 bit.  We found in spring 3.2 there is new feature introduced "automatic log level propagation". Because of that while application is getting shutting down, it changes the log level from INFO to ERROR. We have some call back methods during shutdown. Because of ERROR log level info messages are not printing. We also tried to change the log level in context in call back method. but it is not changing.

Comment: Yes. It is perfectly working in older version.

Comment: The only hit when Googling for `"automatic log level propagation" spring boot` or `"automatic log level propagation" log4j2` is for this question. Can you link to where you learned about it? Also, as Phil requested, a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) is needed here.

Comment: We have shutdownhook ` Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> shutdown()));` when we close the application, it invoke shutdown(), where we gracefully shutdown all component.   We now added this code to see the loglevel in context  during shutting down, it is showing "ERROR ". We never changed from INFO to ERROR in runtime.      
 `String logLevelInContext = LogManager.getContext(false).getLogger("Logger").getLevel().toString();`

Comment: "automatic log level propagation" in spring boot 3.2

Comment: I think we need a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make progress here.

Comment: What does `LogManager.getContext(false).getClass()` give you? My guess is that you get a [`SimpleLoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-api/org/apache/logging/log4j/simple/SimpleLoggerContext.html).

Comment: LogManager.getContext(false).getClass()  is giving me :  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext

Comment: Can you run your application with `-Dlog4j2.debug` and add the shutdown details to your question? During the shutdown sequence the logging backend must also shut down. The big question is whether this happens **before** or **after** you write your last log statement.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz : Thank you for the suggestion, Looks logging is shutting  before. We have activeMq and some other component . When activeMq is shutting down along with it is shutting logging also. After stopping ActiveMq there is no info messages.  below some console logs : ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- -- -- -- -- -- Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
INFO
WARN StatusConsoleListener [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] Ignoring log event after log4j was shut down: INFO

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz , any further suggestion will be very help full. We are recently experiencing this issue, after upgrading the SpringBoot application 3.2 and Java21

Comment: Please add your shutdown logs by **editing** your question. All the necessary information to answer the question should be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz : sure, I have updated the question. Looks disruptor has been shut down. `TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory
DEBUG StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] AsyncLoggerDisruptor: shutting down disruptor for this context.
TRACE StatusLogger [AsyncContext@25bbe1b6] AsyncLoggerDisruptor: disruptor has been shut down.`

Comment: Looks like you are having a problem with the order in which the services are shut down. Is `BaseStateMachineListener` a Spring `EventListener`? If so what is his order?

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz, Looks you correctly point out the issue. BaseStateMachineListener is shutting down early. also we observed we are not getting event from state as it is stopped. Are there any way to give order ?

Comment: Yes, BaseStateMachineListener is a Spring EventListener.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz, I found an issue in log4j2 : Log4j2 shutdown before it prints the last messages during graceful shutdown of spring boot application. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11360 . Any workaround or solution ? It will very helpful, please suggest

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz, I added logging.register-shutdown-hook: false  property , Now it looks working. I will do more test and update. Thanks for support. Could you please tell me the impact of this property ?

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz, with adding logging.register-shutdown-hook: false property, we are getting expected info logs. could you tell us the impact of this property ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is due to the ordering between application listeners: the [`LoggingApplicationListener`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.java) has a very high precedence of:

```java
Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 20
```

This means that the listener is called pretty early at startup, but unless I am mistaken Spring calls listeners in the same order at shutdown.

If your shutdown listener requires logging, it should have a precedence between `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` and `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 19`. Specifying the order can be done either by implementing [`Ordered`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) or using the [`@Order`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation.

Comment: Thank you You really helped a lot. Actually we are disabling the shutdown hook as of now. Actually we also upgraded log4j2 version from 2.17 to 2.18. Looks in 2.18 by default shutdownHook is enabled., so we are disabling now. I will check your suggestion @order. I will update in few days.

Comment: Could you please confirm that in log4j2 2.17 by default shutdownHook is disabled and in 2.18 it is enabled ?

Comment: If you are talking about Log4j Core's (not Spring Boot's) shutdown hook, it is by default **enabled** unless the Servlet API is detected or it is disabled via Log4j properties. Spring Boot disables it via a custom property source (cf. [`SpringBootPropertySource`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/SpringBootPropertySource.java)).